# MaxWidth and MaxHeight Expands Smaller Images Past Their Actuals

Tags: wpf, image, .net-core

When using the `Image` control to load  images on the wpf `Canvas` all works. But certain images are large and *explode* on the surface so I set the `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` to render *those* images within the *max* constraints.

Then the large image loading works, but the side effect is that the smaller than max size and width images are then **Stretched** to the largest size. This is due to the `Stretch` being set whose value is anything other than `None`.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source}"
       Stretch="UniformToFill"
       MaxHeight="200"
       MaxWidth="400"/>
```

[image: Results, No Max on the left, and Max on the right.]

*Left image is w/o max's set. Right image is with maxes set*

---

**The Issue**

Its apparent that I have competing priorities, on one hand later (after initial loading) the image can be resized and that resizing needs the `Stretch` set so it expands to that resize. The initial competing need as discussed is to **load** the images as is, *unless they go over the max sizes*

How can I achieve both based on need; on loading it resizes to max's **only** if greater than maxes? Then after the image load it can have the `Stretch` set to `UniformToFill`?

---

**The Thing Tried**

I tried to set the `Stretch` after the load, but it seemed to have the same effect. I am guessing it is fired **not** after the *Image* loads but unfortunately when the *control* loads; which happens before the image loads.

```
private void LoadedImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Image image)
        image.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting [StretchDirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image.stretchdirection?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @Clemens In testing `StretchDirection` and setting it to `DownOnly`, it shrinks the large and keeps the small *as is* during startup. Check! But it limits the small in future sizing by the user to be oversized.... Hence setting `StretchDirection` is **the answer** and to accomodate the other feature as mentioned, during a hover or resize I will just remove the limitations at that time. Answer the question and I will mark it as the answer. THX!